# How to minify static assets for a Blazor app

Tags: c#, npm, blazor, bundle, minify

### Background

I've been playing with Blazor recently.
I created a sample application using a VS template.

Then I wanted to add some styling to it. So I found an example template [here](https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-dashboard), copied the static assets to `wwwroot` folder, then linked required files in `_Host.cshtml` and everything looks good.

### Questions

I ended up with a lot of files in my `wwwroot` folder:

[image: wwwwroot structure]

##### Question 1

Is there a way to bundle and minify the content of `wwwroot`? I tried naively wiring everything via webpack and it even output something, but then I had no idea how to link the files in `_Host.cshtml`.

##### Question 2

I can see that the same template is available via npm [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-dashboard). I know it is possible to use npm inside Blazor, but would it be possible to fetch the package, then minify it e.g. using webpack and output it to `wwwroot`? If so, how can I link it together with Blazor app then?

Comment: For question 1 I would recommend using [BuildBundlerMinifier](https://www.nuget.org/packages/BuildBundlerMinifier)

[Steps described here](https://www.syncfusion.com/faq/blazor/general/how-do-you-bundle-and-minify-the-css-and-js-files-in-blazor-applications)

You can then specify the name of the bundled and minified file to import in your ```_Host.cshtml``` file

Comment: Thanks. I've seen it as well and I thought that there has been a better solution since the last update time for this package was in 2020. But I'll give it a go anyway. If it works then it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [the Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/bundling-and-minification?view=aspnetcore-7.0), one good way to do this is via [WebOptimizer](https://github.com/ligershark/WebOptimizer).

I would not recommend using the `BuildBundlerMinifier` tool described in the comments above. It's unmaintained, does not work with `dotnet tool`, and has a hard dependency on `.NETCore 2.0` (which can be very disruptive to a workflow — I ended up screwing up my dotnet7 SDK install in attempts to get this working).

OTOH, Weboptimizer handles both bundling and minification directly from within the app itself, i.e., `app.UseWebOptimizer()`.

---

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a go later today,

Comment: can we use WebOptimizer with blazor webassembly as well?